# How to get the minimum item from list depending on condtion in card game

Tags: python

I'm working on a card game my problem is when the user plays card on the table the next player check his cards and plays the card higher than the card on the table if he has or plays the minimum cards from the same card's type on the table, or plays a random card if he hasn't from the same type.

```
class Table(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
       
        self.table_cards=list()
        self.hand_images=Group()

    def add_card_to_table(self,card):
        self.table_cards.append(card)

    def get_max_card_on_table(self):
        if len(self.table_cards)==1:
            return self.table_cards[0]
        else:
            tmp_card=self.table_cards[0]
            for c in self.table_cards:
                if c>tmp_card:
                    tmp_card=c
            return tmp_card

    def get_min_card_on_table(self):
        if len(self.table_cards)==1:
            return self.table_cards[0]
        else:
            tmp_card=self.table_cards[0]
            for c in self.table_cards:
                if c<tmp_card:
                    tmp_card=c
            return tmp_card
```

```
    def check_card_type(self,card):
        # Check if the player has the same card type 
        for c in self.hand:
            if c.card_type==card.card_type:
                return True
        return False

    def get_min_value_card(self,card):
        if self.check_card_type(card):
            tmp_card=card
            for c in self.hand:
                if c<card:
                    tmp_card=c
            self.hand.remove(c)
            return tmp_card

    def get_max_value_card(self,table):
        card=table.get_max_card_on_table()
        if self.check_card_type(card):
            tmp_card=card
            for c in self.hand:
                if c>card:
                    tmp_card=c
                    self.hand.remove(c)
                    return tmp_card
            card=table.get_min_card_on_table()
            tmp_card=self.get_min_value_card(card)
            return tmp_card
        else:
            tmp_card=self.get_random_card() 
            return tmp_card
```

Comment: You [shouldn't use an image here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).
What you have provided in your image can be represented as text formatted as code.
You can [edit] your post to make changes.

Comment: @Kraigolas i apologize sir

Comment: No need for apologies, if you see the link in my comment you'll realize images make it more difficult for many users to answer your question. It's in everyone's best interest that you provide as few images as possible in your questions, but there's nothing to feel bad about! It's just a suggested [edit].

Comment: It looks like there are other blocks of code that make up this game program (for example, there seems to be a player class).  Can you please provide them so that the community can analyze the play of this game.  Thanks.

Comment: @NoDakker Yes sir exactly there is a class player . any way I solved the problem thanks I appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it ...
since the player hand is sorted by card type and value so the first card from any type will be the smallest one so I return the Index of it .

```
def check_card_type(self,card):
        # Check if the player has the same card type 
        for c in self.hand:
            if c.card_type==card.card_type:
                indx=self.hand.index(c)
                return True,indx
        return False,indx

    def get_min_value_card(self,card):
        check,indx=self.check_card_type(card)
        if check:
            return self.get_spcifec_card(indx)
```